# xlsxwriter: add formula with other sheet in it

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I try to create a XLSX file with xlsxwriter python plugin.
In this XLSX, I have 2 sheets:

- **Analyse**: Contain a table with informations
- **Stat**: Contain some informations and 2 formulas

This 2 formulas are:

```
=NBVAL(Analyse!C:C)-1
=NB.SI(Analyse!D:D;"To change")
```

My problem is when I open the generated file, I have a error. And the formulas don't work. If I edit the formula and just press Enter, it work.

My code:

```
shInfo    = self.__workbook.add_worksheet("Stat")
shInfo.activate()

information = self.__workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#BFBFBF',
                                          'font_name': 'Courier New'})

shInfo.write('G3','=NBVAL(Analyse!C:C)-1',information)
shInfo.write('G5','=NB.SI(Analyse!D:D;"To change")',information)
```

When I open the XML error report. I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <logFileName>error056160_04.xml</logFileName>
  <summary>Des erreurs ont été détectées dans le fichier « L:\UNMS\InputBEB\Output\UNMSViewer\public_html\Data\XLSX\todo\A6S54300.xlsx »</summary>
  <removedRecords summary="Liste des enregistrements supprimés ci-dessous :">  
    <removedRecord>Enregistrements supprimés: Formule dans la partie /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml</removedRecord>
    </removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that the formula function names are in French but Excel expects it to be stored/written in [English](http://fr.excel-translator.de/). At least in the files written by XlsxWriter.

Try this instead:

```
shInfo.write('G3','=COUNTA(Analyse!C:C)-1',information)
shInfo.write('G5','=COUNTIF(Analyse!D:D,"To change")',information)
```

If you send me a small sample file saved using a French version of Excel I'll have a look and see if it is possible to set a flag in the files written by XlsxWriter to indicate the language of the formulas.

**Update**: The `COUNTIF()` formula also needs to use the US style comma operator instead of `;`.
**Update 2**: Based on the sample file provided by @gatchan there is no language identifier in the file. The formula is translated to English and US style comma operator, by Excel, when it is saved .

Comment: Thanks! But, same problem. Here is a real example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1122602/D0644060.xlsx

Comment: And there is a near empty XLSX file create with my french Excel: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1122602/sample.xlsx

Comment: Added a fix to the `COUNTIF()` formula. Try it now.

Comment: Many many thanks! That the solution:

Use the formula in English and the comma instead of ;

Comment: Could you still send me a spreadsheet created in the French/Belgian version Excel so that I can analyse it to see if there is a more general solution. Just one worksheet with the following, or similar, formula in cell 'A1': `=NB.SI(D:D;"To change")`

Comment: I change the sample.xlsx store in dropbox.
I add the formula in the first cell

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1122602/sample.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `write()` method you should use [write_formula()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html?highlight=formula#write_formula):

```
shInfo.write_formula('G3','=NBVAL(Analyse!C:C)-1',information)
shInfo.write_formula('G5','=NB.SI(Analyse!D:D;"To change")',information)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I allready test this and I have the same problem :(.

Comment: @gatchan hm, then, just to test, could you omit `=` and see if it works? thanks.

Comment: same problem, that strange... 

maybe because my sheet with data is before my sheet with formulas?

Comment: @gatchan could you show the whole code (as much as you can) so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: here is a small example of the class I wrote and a test case in the __main__ part: http://pastebin.com/MbBdVUpd