# Python xlsxWriter formula name error

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create an Excel workbook with two worksheets - i used xlsxwriter to enter data on the first worksheet, then rank that data on the second worksheet. When i open the workbook, the ranks have an Excel name? error. If i click on the end of the formula in the edit bar, it calculates correctly, so i dont think the formula is incorrect.. i suspect it may be some sort of ordering of operations? My excel sheet is set to automatically calculate formulas... the only similar problem i could find on the web was [xlsxwriter: add formula with other sheet in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850949/xlsxwriter-add-formula-with-other-sheet-in-it), but i cannot tell what the  solution was (if it actually turned out to be something other than a french to english issue)
Here is a simplified version of my code

```
import xlsxwriter
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\Python33\ScoreTry.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.add_worksheet('RawScores')
ws2 = wb.add_worksheet('RankScores')
ws1.write(0,0,32)
ws1.write(1,0,39)
ws1.write(2,0,15)
for i in range (0,3):
    x =  'IF(isblank(RawScores!A'+str(i+1)+'),"",RANK.AVG(RawScores!A'+str(i+1)+',RawScores!A$1:A$100,0))'
    ws2.write_formula(i,0,x)
wb.close()
```

my RankScores worksheet opesn with three #NAME? errors instead of ranks until i click enter on each. Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`RANK.AVG()` is a function that was added as an "extension" after the original XLSX file format specification. There is a list of these functions defined in the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd907480%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So, although the formula is displayed as `RANK.AVG()` it is stored in the file as `_xlfn.RANK.AVG()` (as listed in the previous doc).

If you change your formula to use the prefixed version of the function it should work.

This is a kludgy but currently unavoidable workaround (without some equally kludgey workaround in the module). For what it is worth it is documented in the [`write_formula()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-formula) section of the docs.